# Getting user to login, then checking if someone is logged in already

Tags: authentication, mysql, session, python

I'm horrible at security so I was curious if you guys had any ideas. I recently wrote an application in Python that I will be selling to select people. The information on the application is private (not incredibly so, I just need a minimal solution). How could I have a user login to the application (from a MySQL database), then have the program check is someone is logged in already under those credentials. Here is a basic flow:

1. User opens the EXE (cx_freezed python file)
2. Program asks user for their login (from a MySQL database)
3. Program checks if someone is already logged in using that info
4. If someone is logged in, don't let them log in. If someone isn't, log them in.

I have absolutely no idea where to start with this, any suggestions/directions to point me?

Comment: You have not given us enough information to help you. Is the database stored on the user's computer or a server? Is the user's session local to the computer or exists on a server? Is there a logoff function?

Comment: It's stored on a MySQL database hosted online. Yes there is a logoff function.

Comment: Not letting someone log on is a strange choice. What will happen if a user logs on and then their computer crashes? How will they log in if they can't log out? Also, if an attacker manages to log in as you, you won't be able to log in to change your password or anything. I think ending the original session generally works better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't be a Dave and roll your own security system. Use an existing one if you can
2. This shouldn't have anything to do with your database. If you happen to persist session info to the db, that's fine, but your session-management should be in-memory
3. Basically you should have a list of authenticated users in memory somewhere in application state. `if authenticatedSessions.get($username) != null then deny`
4. Concurrent Session Control is a PITA for users. Example: You login just before leaving work, then get in your car, try to login from your mobile, and now you can't. Consider allowing 2 concurrent sessions, or keep the timeout short

Spring Security (Java) has this feature. It's open source so you could "gain inspiration" it: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-concurrent-sessions

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to avoid writing my own deal from scratch hence this post. Also there is a very specific usage case for this application where no one should have to be logged in on two systems regardless of the case.

Comment: @DanielYveson is this a desktop application talking directly to a remote sql database? or is there an application server inbetween?

Comment: Directly at this moment